# How to compare multiple PDF files?

Tags: pdf, comparison, ocr

My professor just uploaded an updated set of all the slides of the whole semester (17 PDFs), referring to them as the now definite examination material.

Problem is, I have made lots of notes on the old set of slides and I don't want to lose all the work I've put in. Since my prof randomly deleted or added some slides to the new set I'd prefer to automate the task of comparing the old and new slide sets somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not mentioned system or tool, here is my solution 
for comparing the text, assuming that are not scanned images.
It should work on any Unix, Cygwin and I guess also Msys.

```
$ pdftotext.exe old-slide.pdf
$ pdftotext.exe new-slide.pdf
$ diff -uN old-slide.txt new-slide.txt| tee -a slides.diff
```

`pdftotext` is part of `poppler` while `diff` of `diffutils`

Of course if the PDF files have a sequence name and similar names, it is possible to automate with a loop for all the files.